# Purpose of setting debug="false" in log4j at configuration level

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, logback, slf4j

What is the purpose of setting attributes at configuration level in `log4j.xml`?

```xml
<log4j:configuration 
    xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="false" threshold="info">
```

Answer (score 1):

In log4j 1.x as well as logback, the `debug="true"` instruction enables the display of messages **internal** to the logging library. In log4j 1.x and logback, the internal messages are independent of logging and loggers. It follows that the `debug="true"` instruction is unrelated to setting levels on loggers.

In logback, these internal messages are called [status messages](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting). See also the "[shorthand](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configDebug)" section a few paragraphs below.

In log4j 2.x, the [internal messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting) followed a different logic but was simplified in version 2.9 and later.